# Where did my package/reward go for getting a rank up in reputation go?

Tags: ps4, destiny

I just got rank 1 in Vanguard reputation, and talked to Zavala for my reward. I picked the one that had a guaranteed legendary weapon (by pushing X with the cursor over it). It said I only got some motes of light and glimmer, though. I checked my inventory and equipment, and there's nothing. A similar thing happened with the cryptarch. What am I missing? How do I get my reward?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Destiny wiki](http://destiny.wikia.com/wiki/Vanguard):

> Starting at rank 3, Guardians will receive one to two Legendary items (not engrams) in the mail every time they rank up.

So, you will only receive weapons/armour when you reach Rank 3

Comment: Then why did it give me items to choose from?

Comment: @Kat No idea, Bungie might not have thought about changing the three packages.

Comment: So it gives you the same dialog for every rank but you don't actually get the items until rank 3?

Comment: @Kat Yes, that is correct. This happened to me as well.